# Azure Devops pull-request conflict on complete

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, pull-request, git-merge-conflict

Probably this is for a lot of users, a simple question, but I can't figure it out right now.

Situation, in Azure Devops Git repositories we have multiple branches:

- master (main development)
- Acceptation (Acceptation branche)
- Production (Production branche)

I want to merge changes from master into Acceptation right now, in the pull request pre-validation, no merge conflicts are found. However, when I complete the PR with rebase and fast-foward (limited to only this option due to policies), I get a merge conflict.

I don't know how to see what the conflict is (I already have an azure devops extention installed, to see file conflicts, this gives nothing). Changes done in acceptance directly, are already merged into master also, to prevent file conflicts.

Also a re-merge of the PR gives the same results.

What else could I try to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I don’t know how to see what the conflict is (I already have an azure
> devops extention installed, to see file conflicts, this gives
> nothing). Changes done in acceptance directly, are already merged into
> master also, to prevent file conflicts.

You can make use of the below extension to resolve your merge conflicts:-

[image]

I created one main branch and Acceptation and Production Branch in Azure DevOps repos like below:-

I created on the conflict in both the branches like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Resolved conflict like below:-

[image]

If Conflict Resolution is applied, Rebase and fast forward does not work so just merged it with fast forward:-

[image]

Created Pull request from main branch to Acceptation like below without any conflicts:-

[image]

[image]

Merge was successful:-

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, You can check the merge conflicts with below git commands:-

```
git checkout <target branch>
git merge <source branch>
```

Cancel merge by running -

```
git merge --abort
```

To resolve the conflict run

```
git merge --continue
```

list file with merge conflicts

```
git status
```

List conflicting merge

```
git log merge
```

Refer here for additional methods to resolve merge conflicts:-

[Resolve Git merge conflicts - Azure Repos | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=git-command-line)

[git - How to resolve merge conflicts in Azure DevOps current UI - DevOps Stack Exchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/9895/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-azure-devops-current-ui)

Comment: I have this extension, and its not showing anything

Comment: You have  to make shure that you are using 1 of the following Azure DevOps Services, 
Team Foundation Server 2017, Team Foundation Server 2018, Azure DevOps Server 2019, or Azure DevOps Server 2020, because we have 2022 version and has autentication problems.